# rshiny: output doesn't change

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble with the drop-down menu options and their outputs.  Although I can see the list of options the output remains the same and doesn't change even though the user can pick a different person. Any suggestions are welcome! My code is below (I removed some sensitive information):

server.r

```
senators <- read.csv("senators.csv")
output$senator <- renderUI({
  selectInput("variablex",
              #inputID = "senator",
              label = "Choose a U.S Senator from the list",
              selected = senators$name,
              choices = senators$name)
  })

  senTweets <- read.csv("person.year.count.csv")
  
  person <- reactive({
    req(variablex)
    df <- senTweets %>% 
      group_by(input$variablex, year) %>% 
      top_n(input$a, n) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(word, -n)
  return(df)
  })
  
  observe({
    df = input$df
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    person () %>%  mutate(word = reorder(word, n))
      ggplot(aes(word, n, fill = factor(year))) +
      geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
      facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free") + scale_fill_viridis_d() +
      coord_flip() + labs(y="Word frequency", x="Term", title = paste("Top words used in 2020"))
    
  })
  
}
```

ur.r

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Main", tabName = "Main", icon = icon("r-project")),
    menuItem("ReadMe", tabName = "ReadMe", icon = icon("readme"))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Main",
  
      sidebarPanel(
        helpText("text"),
        uiOutput('senator'),
        
        sliderInput(
          "a",
          label = "Select value to view top common words",
          min = 1,
          max = 10,
          value = 5
          ),
        ),
      
      
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
     
     
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "ReadMe", 
            includeMarkdown("README.md"))
    ),
  )
)
```

UPDATE: I made the following changes as gss suggested but I still can't get the output to change, any tips? Also not sure if the observe made a difference but I added that line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try some debugging. I don't have data which you have, so I don't see other possibilities. After reading your code there are two parts which I'm not sure if there are correct. Here is the first part:

```
person <- reactive({
    #req(variablex)
    df <- senTweets %>% 
      group_by(input$variablex, year) %>% 
      top_n(input$a, n) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(word, -n)
  })
```

First of all, `input$variablex` is a name (senator's name), right? (Or should be at least). So I assume that `senTweets` data contains **columns** with the names which are present in `senators$name`. Otherwist it won't be possible to group by. `input$variablex`, as all inputs from shiny, is of type `character`, so the first thing is that you should probably use some knowledge about programming with `dplyr` ([Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) and use `.data[[input$variablex]]`:

```
person <- reactive({
    #req(variablex)
    df <- senTweets %>% 
      group_by(.data[[input$variablex]], year) %>% 
      top_n(input$a, n) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(word, -n)
  })
```

This should not be a problem with `input$a` because it is just a number and even if `top_n()` function expects number, probably there are a implicit type conversion.

You can change the code according my adive or first you can check if you really get what you want when user chooses senator's name. To do this, add `browser()` function here:

```
person <- reactive({
    #req(variablex)
    df <- senTweets %>% 
      group_by(input$variablex, year) %>% 
      top_n(input$a, n) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(word, -n)
browser()
  })
```

(you may need to add `req(input$variablex)` at the beginning, otherwise it can be that you do not choose any senator and after opening the app, you will immediately will be moved to the console in RStudio)

When you open the app, choose senator, then go back to RStudio and you should be in debugging mode. Type `df` in the console and check if this table looks as you think it should.

The second part of your code which seems suspicious is this one:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    person () %>%  mutate(word = reorder(word, n))
      ggplot(data = person(), aes(word, n, fill = factor(year))) +
      geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
      facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free") + scale_fill_viridis_d() +
      coord_flip() + labs(y="Word frequency", x="Term", title = paste("Top words used in 2020"))
    
  })
```

Especially this: `person () %>%  mutate(word = reorder(word, n))` (it changes `person()` data, but do not save those changes!) doesn't seem to do anything useful. More sense would be to have:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    person () %>%  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(word, n, fill = factor(year))) +
      geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
      facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free") + scale_fill_viridis_d() +
      coord_flip() + labs(y="Word frequency", x="Term", title = paste("Top words used in 2020"))

  })
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! I added your suggestion for browser and req(input$variablex) however I get an error that there's no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL". Do you think it would be better to move the mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) from the output$plot to person <- reactive({ ? I'm assuming it would still save those changes.

Comment: UPDATE: i moved it to see what it would do but I would get errors with the aes(word, n, fill = factor(year))) as plot and layer1 is missing year